# Is the 'autoscaling' setting for the nginx-ingress helm chart working?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I tried to deploy a nginx-ingress using the `autoscaling` setting inside the `values.yaml` file, but it seems that it does not work.

```
  autoscaling:
    enabled: false
  #  minReplicas: 1
  #  maxReplicas: 11
  #  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 50
```

I try to deploy a nginx-ingress like this

```
helm upgrade --install ingress --set \
controller.service.type=NodePort,\
controller.service.nodePorts.http=$http_nodePort,\
controller.service.nodePorts.https=$https_nodePort,\
rbac.create=true,\
controller.replicaCount=$ingress_replicas,\
controller.stats.enabled=true,\
controller.metrics.enabled=true,\
controller.autoscaling.enabled=true,\
controller.autoscaling.minReplicas=1,\
controller.autoscaling.maxReplicas=10,\
controller.autoscaling.targetCPUUtilizationPercentage=50 \
stable/nginx-ingress
```

but I get this error

```
Release "ingress" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: release ingress failed: HorizontalPodAutoscaler.autoscaling "ingress-nginx-ingress-controller" is invalid: spec.metrics[1].resource.targetAverageUtilization: Required value: must set either a target raw value or a target utilization
```

Does anyone has managed to use the autoscaling setting, or you just deploy manually an HPA?

**EDIT 1**
I tried the same `helm upgrade ...` command with a local copy of the ingress chart which is the following [a bit old]:

```
name: nginx-ingress
version: 0.11.1
appVersion: 0.11.0
```

and it creates the HPA fine! However, I would prefer to deploy it using the stable chart repo.

The current chart version [is this](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/Chart.yaml) .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like configuration is inconsistent or [helm](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/) is not providing every parameter to [nginx-ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) installation in the [horizontal-autoscale](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/) environment.

I’ve looked at  templates/controller-hpa.yaml of nginx-ingress chart, and I think missed variable is:

`controller.autoscaling.targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage=<value>`